# plone4: open overlay with ajax content w/o binding to click

Tags: javascript, plone, jquery-tools

`$('.selector').prepOverlay()` from `plone.app.jquerytools` works fine when binding a popup to 'onClick' and load it's content from the url provided by one of the href/src/rel attributes.

`<a class=".selector" href="link/to/@@view">link</a>`

i've got the usecase where i load my content via ajax manually, check it for certain conditions and if these are met i want to show the content returned by the ajax request in an overlay:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: portal_url + '/@@my-popup',
    success: function(r) {
        if (r != '') {

            // show Overlay

        }
    }
});
```

what i currently do to show the overlay is:

create a link item, bind an overlay to it and open it

```
var link = $('<a href="' + portal_url + '/@@my-popup"></a>')

link.prepOverlay({
    subtype:'ajax',
});
link.click();
```

however, this results in two requests for '/@@my-popup'

is there a nicer way to get arbitrary content into the overlays created with prepOverlay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately not.

If you look closer to the `prepOverlay` function, you see the following line:

```
// be promiscuous, pick up the url from
// href, src or action attributes
src = o.attr('href') || o.attr('src') || o.attr('action');
```

This means you're not able to trigger the overlay, without having a element with href, src or action attribute.

You may write your own prepOverlay method, wich does not iterate over some elements, but takes a specific url as param.

Comment: thanks for your reply mathias. this would also be a valid option.
in fact - this might be better than using jquertools overlay directly because i get the same look and feel for my popups and i can re-use the event handlers i'm using for other popups)

Answer (score 4):

The only real purpose of Plone's prepOverlay is to automate the conversion of links or images into simple jquerytools overlays. In your case, it's just getting in the way. So, don't use prepOverlay. Just directly use [jquerytools' overlay facility](http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/overlay/index.html).

Comment: this is what i learned too steve. however using it directly required to copy quite a lot of code from prepOverlay to get the same markup for popups

Comment: .. and make it compatible with custom events i registered for prepoverlay popups. (the pbo.create_content_div method is not usable outside of overlayhelper.js)